# tlmgr proxy on Windows

Tags: packages, texlive, installing, windows

I have TeX Live installed on Windows 7. I need some additional packages. The computer sits behind a proxy, so tlmgr does not work. I couldn't find any mentioning of proxies in the tlmgr documentation. When I tried to search on the Internet, all the information I found assumes a Unix system.

How can I setup the computer to use tlmgr?

Answer (score 4):

`tlmgr` uses one of two download methods: The preferred ones is `LWP` (Perl module), if that fails, it falls back to `wget`. `LWP` supports proxying, thus it *should* work (I cannot confirm it as I don't have a proxy running).

What you need is documented in the LWP manpage, but I copy it here:

```
   http_proxy
   ftp_proxy
   xxx_proxy
   no_proxy
       These environment variables can be set to enable communication
       through a proxy server.  See the description of the "env_proxy"
       method in LWP::UserAgent.
```

We already set enable proxies in the `LWP` instance, so it should be enough to set the `http_proxy` variable (and export it).

Incidentally (not really), `wget` evaluates the same variables, so in case the `LWP` method fails, also `wget` should use the proxy.

Comment: Under MS Windows open a command line and type `set http_proxy=<your proxy settings>`. Under Linus the same but with `export` instead of `set`.